# CSS styling on DIV chrome ignoring the overflow hidden

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image]I have a div with a width of 200px and overflow set to hidden. In Firefox, Safari & IE the select obeys the style rule and displays correctly. However in chrome the select element doesnt follow the rule set and flows over the div.

The site is at http://conaty.hailstormcommerce.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=20

this issue was with the background property of the select element.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some images (upload to an image service, someone with editing priviliges will add them to your post) to illustrate your problem. For once the problem has been fixed the link will no longer be of any use to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have described the issue incorrectly in your question.

It looks like you're trying to create a custom drop down arrow for the `select` element. The `select` element is the correct width you set and the overflow is hidden by the div. However, in Chrome, the `select` has a white background that covers your custom arrow and is unaffected by your `background: transparent !important;` declaration.

To fix this so that your custom arrow shows through, you just need to add `-webkit-appearance: none;` as below:

```
.selectContainer select {
    background: transparent !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* add this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT` is known to behave like this. It behaves more like a control in the OS than an element in HTML (as do radio buttons and checkboxes). All you can do is hard-code the width to prevent it from overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Diodeus answer, you have min-width of 220px specified on this element.

Do this:

```
width:100%;
min-width:0;
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm trying to achieve the effect where the dropdown arrow is hidden behind the image.